# cakephp ClassRegistry::init issue

Tags: cakephp

I am using the ClassRegistry::init method to instantiate some models in side another Model.

So I Have

app/Model/Report.php
app/Model/KPI/Factory.php

I have included the Models in the KPI folder using:

```
App::build(array(
    'Model' => array(APP . 'Model' . DS . 'KPI' . DS)
));
```

Using the models from controllers is ok. But when using ClassRegistry::init with Report.php I get a strange error saying "Class could no be redeclared".

Even more strange is the fact that it works find on Windows but it fails on Linux.

Thanks

Comment: `Class could no be redeclared` means that that Model is already loaded. When something works on Windows but fails on Linux; in most cases the path is incorrect. Windows is NOT case sensitive and Linux is.

Comment: please debug APP . 'Model' . DS . 'KPI' . DS

Comment: What do you mean moyend?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the App::build method is used to add additional directories to your path.  Everything in the Model directory should be auto loaded by Cake even if it is in a subdirectory so you don't need App::build.  Assuming the Factory class is declared as

```
class Factory extends AppModel {}
```

then you should be able to use it with

```
ClassRegistry::init('Factory')
```

If you have multiple subdirectories with a class called "factory" then rename them like KPI_Factory and use

```
ClassRegistry::init('KPI_Factory')
```

Note, this all untested, but hopefully puts you on the right track.